# Why can I only access certain language specfic tags via "Tags" page?

Tags: support, bug, tags, search, tag-search

On certain language specific tags (I'm not exactly sure what there called), I can only search with them via the "Tags" page. I believe this is a bug, or perhaps a unknown feature of some kind?

For example, early today, I was trying to find questions related to [scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheme). I typed "scheme" in the search box, but the search term was not surrounded in square brackets like most language-tag searches. And there was no language info shown:

> [image]

*However*, when I went to the "Tags" page. Typed in scheme in the search bar, and clicked on the scheme tag when it was found, Stack Overflow recognized the language-tag, and surrounded it in its usually square brackets.

> [image]

Along with showing the language information:

> [image]

Why is this?  Why can I only access the scheme language tag from the Tags page, instead of directly typing it into the search box?

I tried this with a few more language specific tags such as [lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lisp), [clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure), and [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) and they also produced the same results as described above.

Does Stack Overflow dislike functional languages? But in all seriousness, why does this happen, and how(if it is possible)can I use these language specific tags directly from the search bar?

Answer (score 2):

Testing tags for the described behaviour with the help of [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/618128/772413/) suggests it only happens for the top 120 tags according to the number of questions. Note that the SEDE results are slightly out-of-date; and so while the cutoff still is between [google-app-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine) and [azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure), [azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure) has overtaken [google-app-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine) at some point in the recent past.