# Why are the search results for "jenkins" different from "[jenkins]"?

Tags: bug, search

When I type `docker` in the Stack Overflow search box, it automatically converts it to `[docker]`, so the result for `docker` are the same as the results for `[docker]`.

But when I search for `jenkins`, it does not convert it to `[jenkins]`, so the result of search is different. Why is `docker` replaced and not `jenkins`?

Comment: related : Meta.SE [Why are search queries inconsistently converted into tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146311/why-are-search-queries-inconsistently-converted-into-tags)

Comment: @Drag and Drop yes I searched a lot but I could not find that one

Comment: For the why, there is a metric ton of tag on SO https://stackoverflow.com/tags.  ~ 63k . 
I don't know the exact number of word that can turn to tag. From a quick test, XAML is turn into a tag and it's on the 4 page. around #119 now. I assume that it's the top 120 now.

Comment: @DragandDrop yeah, 120 seems to be the cut-off: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1269280 see also:https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165594/158100

Comment: Indeed -- cf. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341937 for an additional rediscovery of this cutoff.

Answer (score 8):

Only the top 60 tags are auto matched and converted per this [Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274235/allow-the-ability-to-search-for-words-which-are-the-names-of-tags-without-being). Note that [this Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165594/158100) suggests that for Stack Overflow the number is 120 rather than 60.

The first answer also explains that

> There is a way to override it. You can simply surround the word with quotation marks. So "security" would search for the word security and not get converted to a tag.

Comment: Is there any reason behind this decision? as a user when I'm searching for docker I can click bounties button  to see those questions, but when I search for jenkins no bounties button exist so I think that there is no bounties on this tag, however when I change it to [jenkins] I can see there are bounties question on this tag

Comment: There is many reference about 60 tags. But XAML turn into one and it's around number 120.

Comment: maybe it is 120 for SO? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165594/158100